# put a button on the Relative Layout and move it independently

Tags: android, rotation, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I have a layout that always rotate to the north. I want to put a pointer on it, but pointer should not rotate. how can I do that? 
this is my code of Layout:

```
rll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(co.iman.R.id.relativeLayout1);
rlllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rlllp.setMargins(190, 200, 200, 0);
```

and in other method I rotate the layout with:

```
    rll.setRotation(mCurrentDegree);
```

I want put a pic or button exactlly in center of this layout? and I want to move this button independently.

Answer (score 0):

Try making another RelativeLayout inside your first one, and do something like this:
`rll.setRotation(mCurrentDegree);`
`rll2.setRotation(-mCurrentDegree);`

Now the inside layout should be set to -10 degrees when its parent is set to 10, so it will look like it is not moving at all. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok. it's good. but I don't think that is useful. bcz I want to move the pointer. it will not be in fix position :(

Comment: As long as you keep the code I mentioned, you should be able to use other functions to move it around as well.

Comment: It's so hard work and confusing :) ... I did it finally...I put my relativeLayout and ImageView on a frameLayout... and problem solved